# How to add multiple languages in codeigniter site

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual

I am developing a site with codeigniter, i want to include multiple language in that site. That is my home page contain a drop down list with multiple language. By selecting each language the over all site should be change to the selected language. How it is possible in codeigniter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do not post the questions right away... please invest some time and try to google it. This was really simple question..

Answer (score 2):

[Codeigniter Language Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html)

> The Language Class provides functions to retrieve language files and
>   lines of text for purposes of internationalization.
>
> In your CodeIgniter system folder you'll find one called language
>   containing sets of language files. You can create your own language
>   files as needed in order to display error and other messages in other
>   languages.
>
> Language files are typically stored in your system/language directory.
>   Alternately you can create a folder called language inside your
>   application folder and store them there. CodeIgniter will look first
>   in your application/language directory. If the directory does not
>   exist or the specified language is not located there CI will instead
>   look in your global system/language folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [this tutorial](http://sumonbd.wordpress.com/2009/09/16/develop-multilingual-site-using-codeigniter-i18n-library/). Hope it will be helpful.